# How to draw circles with RVIZ markers?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I would like to indicate a special zone around an object (for instance a cube) in RVIZ by a marker. I have looked at the [basic_marker tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines)  and it is possible to creat this zone by a `LINE_STRIP`. But I was wondering if we can create a one like the [Interactive Markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Getting%20Started). I have looked the documents and I did not find that the circle around the object like the one on `ChessPiece` is configurable.

Do you have any idea how to do it correctly?

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326136/how-to-draw-circles-with-rviz-markers?/) by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 264 on 2019-06-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-06-18**:
Assuming you just want the circle to look the same as the one used by the interactive markers then you can reproduce it using a triangle list marker and setting the alpha transparency of the whole marker to around 50%.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-18**:
There are marker types for `CUBE`, `SPHERE` and `CYLINDER`. Would those be sufficient for what you're trying to do?

A circle can be made from a really flat cylinder.

or does it need to be an 'open' circle (ie: not a filled one)?

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-06-19**:
thanks for your comment @gvdhoorn, I found exactly the `CYLINDER` shape marker as the easiest solution.

**Comment by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) on 2019-06-19**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I understood, based on your application and your requirement there exist different solutions. For my case as @gvdhoorn mentioned it can be solved by a `CYLINDER` shape marker.

---

Originally posted by [Mobile_robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/11921/mobile_robot/) with karma: 264 on 2019-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1